# JPA Many to One: Deleting One to Many side

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following relationship

```
Class UserAccount{

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "firstSharedBy")
private List<Images> imagesFirstShared;

}

Class Images{

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn
private UserAccount firstSharedBy;
}
```

I want to delete a UserAccount instance. So I do this.

```
 userAccount.getImagesFirstShared().clear();
 entityManager.remove(userAccount);
```

But it throws the following exception

```
 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`Images`, CONSTRAINT `FK201C4A25D4C117` FOREIGN KEY (`firstSharedBy_USER_NAME`) REFERENCES `USERACCOUNT` (`USER_NAME`))
```

Anyone with any clue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove images from database when you delete user account, you need to add `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` property to `@OneToMany` annotation and remove line `userAccount.getImagesFirstShared().clear();`.

If you don't want to delete these images, then you should make a loop over images, set `firstSharedBy` property to null and save each `Images` entity. And only then you will be able to delete `UserAccount` entity, because it will not have constrainted connections.

Comment: No I don't want to remove. So I will have to loop through all the image objects and set firstSharedBy null wherever the UserAccount object is the one I am going to delete. Is that right? If so isn't that untidy and inefficient, especially when I have a very big list of images?

Comment: Yes, but I can't mind another way to do it. It's hibernate :]

Comment: Running a query instead of looping through would be a lot more cleaner  IMHO. Let me see if it is possible. Anyways thanks.

Comment: Hibernate is good, but in some cases it provides not as brilliant solutions as you want )